# Linear progress bar on Material-UI card

Tags: material-ui

Is it possible to have a linear progress indicator on the bottom or top border of a Material-UI card? i.e. the full width of the card, no padding. I *think* I've seen this used in some Google apps (though I can't find it anywhere now I'm looking).

If not, is there a better way to indicate a card is loading?

In my case, the card has some content and is waiting for a live response from a support agent, so it's intended to indicate the card will get additional information when it is ready.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies - putting `<LinearProgress />` as the last element in the `<Card>`, not in the `<CardContent>`, worked

Comment: This does not seem to work in mui5. Will add a solution if I find one.

Comment: Looking for this exact thing in Mui5 - @Jack, any luck?

Comment: @Sasgorilla yes. Thanks for the reminder. You can force it in mui5 by following the above mentioned answer and adding a padding of 0px to the Card component and 10px (or anything >0) to the CardContent component